# form not submitted in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, error-handling, mern

I'm trying to send information from the the client side to the server side in a full stack MERN application using a form, but the form isn't submitting here is the code:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
export default () => {
    //keep track of what is being typed via useState hook
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(""); 
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
    //handler when the form is submitted
    const onSubmitHandler = e => {
        //prevent default behavior of the submit
        e.preventDefault();
        //make a post request to create a new person
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/people', {
            firstName,
            lastName
        })
            .then(res=>console.log(res))
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
    //onChange to update firstName and lastName
    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
            <p>
                <label>First Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setFirstName(e.target.value)} value={firstName}/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Last Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setLastName(e.target.value)} value={lastName}/>
            </p>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

I get the following error:
[image]

I couldn't figure out the problem, double checked everything searched the internet = nothing

Please help!

Comment: Is the backend server running?

Comment: How do I make sure it is running? are you saying they should run simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. The backend server should be running in order to process the connection request by the React frontend and Express backend.

Comment: Aha I see the problem is solved I used two different consoles one for the server side which I ran using nodemon server.js and one for the client side which I ran using npm run start Thank you so much I appreciate your help!!

Comment: I have one more question is this the right approach? and do I have to do this every time I want to post the form info?

Comment: Yes, the server needs to be running in the background for api requests to be processed. If it answered your question, please mark it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your NodeJS server is not running in the background. You should run it while making any API requests via your backend.

Comment: Understood. Thank you sir you saved my day and a couple of projects I had them stashed with the same issue lol